# Can't select external script editor in Unity3D

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio-code

in Unity3D 2020.3.32f1 when I try to select my external script editor via **Edit->Preferences->External Tools->External Script Editor**  the file dialog opens and I try to select VSCode. So far so good.

Now the problem is that **I can't select any of the applications listed in the file-dialog window because all applications are greyed out!**

I have to mention that in my case Unity3D and Visual Studio Code are installed on an external SSD-drive on my Mac (using Big Sur 11.6.1). But this should be no problem at all.

My first thought was that the problem has to do with some file-permissions so I checked them but couldn't find something unusual. Also I checked the 'Security & Privacy'-prefPane and made sure that Unity3D has access to removable volumes.

Please, can someone help me out? TIA.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I just found an interesting (though cumbersome) workaround:

- Right click on the greyed file name
- Select "Quick Look"
- Close the "Quick Look" window
- Now the file will be highlighted and you can hit "open" (or double click).